# sign of parametrically dependent eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, parametric

I calculate numerically eigenvalues and eigenvectors of some parametrically dependent operator $\hat{H}(R)$. So after representation of this operator in some basis set I have matrix $\mathbb{H}(R)$ which after diagonalization have a form $\mathbb{Z}(R) \mathbb{D}(R) \mathbb{Z}(R)^{-1}$ where $\mathbb{Z}(R)$ are obtained eigenvectors for some particular value of parameter $R$.

My problem is that I need to calculate derivative with respect to parameter $R$ of these eigenvectors. But as you probably know normalized eigenvectors are defined up to some sign, so $-\mathbb{Z}(R)$ also are eigenvectors of my operator. Unfortunately numerical libraries for diagonalization (such as LAPACK for example) produce eigevectors with this uncertainty, which make the numerical calculation of derivative $d \mathbb{Z}(R) / d R$ 
impossible.

Can some of you suggest more or less general way to adjust sign of eigenvectors on different points of parameter's grid? I know about some methods like adjusting sign of extreme points but they don't satisfy me.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Two stupid questions and an idea : is what you call an "operator" is initially (i.e., prior to any numerical discretization) finite dimensional or infinite dimensional ? Can you say the order of magnitude of this finite dimension ? A first idea I had about your problem is is to ensure at each step that the "bunch of eigenvectors" shares a same hemisphere of the unit nD sphere.

Comment: Initially my operator is defined on Hilbert space which means infinite dimensions. However the operator is localized, so I can numerically good enough to define the representation of my operator in some localized basis. Usually the dimension of this representation is around few tens of thousands. Your idea about getting the eigenvectors from the same hemisphere is definitely good. Do you have also an idea how to realize it numerically?